SVG Symbol Not Rendering in Vue 3 with Vite - Only One Icon Failing
I'm working on a Vue 3 project using Vite, and I'm encountering an issue with SVG symbols not rendering correctly. Specifically, one of my icons (check-circle) does not show up when used as a symbol reference, while all other icons in the same SVG sprite file render without any problems.
I've also posted a bug report on Vite with full details
But I want to know if this is:

SVG problem
Vue problem
Vite problem
Browser problem
Caching of JS problem
or other type of problem.

Here's what I've done so far:

SVG Symbol Definitions: I have an SVG sprite file that defines multiple symbols, including search, hamburger, notification, play, dots-vert, and check-circle. All of these icons are defined similarly:

<symbol id="check-circle" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
    <path d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12S6.5 22 12 22 22 17.5 22 12 17.5 2 12 2M10 17L5 12L6.41 10.59L10 14.17L17.59 6.58L19 8L10 17Z" />
</symbol>


Usage in Vue Component: I am referencing these symbols in my Vue component like this:

<bek-icon icon="/public/ui-icons.svg#check-circle" />

All other icons render perfectly, but the check-circle icon does not appear.

Troubleshooting Steps:

Checked the SVG file for syntax errors or inconsistencies.
Verified that the symbol ID matches the reference in the Vue component.
Tested the SVG directly in HTML, and the check-circle icon renders correctly.
Inspected with developer tools, and the use element is present but not rendering the icon.


Configuration: I'm using Vite for development, and here's part of my Vite config for handling SVGs:


export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '~': fileURLToPath(new URL('/public', import.meta.url)),
    }
  }
})

My Question:
Why is only the check-circle icon failing to render when used as a symbol in my Vue component, while all other icons work fine? Could this be related to Vite's handling of the SVG file, or is there something wrong with how the symbol is defined or used? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:

Vue 3
Vite
SVG sprite file in /public directory
Icons used as SVG symbols


If you want to know if it's a browser problem, try another browser e.g. Firefox.

I can't reproduce anything substantial in https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/otabekoff/vitejs-vite-tco99a?file=src/views/HomeView.vue or the repo it's based on. It's more flaky on stackblitz due to the way it works but works more or less consistently. "WHY IT DOESN'T WORK FOR THE FIRST TIME WITH /" - because an update in .svg won't trigger hot reload, the files from public/ aren't bundled and loaded once as regular resources. It will be loaded again if you reload the page or change url.

"path form / to /public/" - but /public/ui-icons.svg is wrong url, this is not how "public" folder is supposed to work in vite. It was good->bad->good url, so the image was reloaded with updated contents. If the problem you described in the question is the same as in the repo, this is not a real problem but the way how it works. You can see what's going on in devtools network requests in case you have doubts

You have fill="none" and no stroke. Try changing the fill or give it a stroke

Ah, I see the problem. And the issue was that Vite doesn't know what is an SVG file. I think I have to teach how to work with SVG files to Vite using a plugin.

I thought Vite handles all and everything goes smooth. I've implemented a custom plugin already as a workaround or fix. Now, working on it to enhance it. Maybe I may publish as an NPM package.

Elimate all (oldskool) dependencies
Create a modern native JavaScript <svg-icon> Web Component,
creating icons client-side
No path issues, no ID issues, no symbol issues, no external file issues...
So HTML:
<svg-icon is="search"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="hamburger" color="green"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="notification" color="blue"></svg-icon>

Outputs:

All code required:


<style>
  svg-icon svg { width: 90px;background: khaki;cursor: pointer }
  svg-icon:hover path { stroke: black }
</style>

<svg-icon is="search"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="play"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="dots-vert"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="check-circle"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="hamburger" color="green"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="notification" color="blue"></svg-icon>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["is", "color"]; // define attributes that trigger change
    }
    attributeChangedCallback() { // handle observedAttributes changes
      this.connectedCallback();
    }
    connectedCallback(color = this.getAttribute("color") || "black") {
      let is = this.getAttribute("is") || "notification";
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24'>` +
        `<g fill="${color}">` + {
          "play":`<path d="M8,5.14V19.14L19,12.14L8,5.14Z" />`,
          "search": `<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="m10.1 17.3c1.6 0 3.1-.5 4.3-1.4l4.7 4.8c.4.4 1.1.4 1.6 0 .4-.5.4-1.2 0-1.6l-4.7-4.8c.8-1.2 1.3-2.6 1.3-4.2 0-3.9-3.2-7.1-7.2-7.1-3.9 0-7.1 3.2-7.1 7.1 0 4 3.2 7.2 7.1 7.2zm0-2.3c2.7 0 4.9-2.2 4.9-4.9 0-2.7-2.2-4.8-4.9-4.8-2.7 0-4.8 2.1-4.8 4.8 0 2.7 2.1 4.9 4.8 4.9z"/>`,
          "hamburger": `<path d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z"/>`,
          "dots-vert": `<circle cx="12" cy="6" r="2"/><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"/><circle cx="12" cy="18" r="2"/>`,
          "check-circle": `<path d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12S6.5 22 12 22 22 17.5 22 12 17.5 2 12 2M10 17L5 12L6.41 10.59L10 14.17L17.59 6.58L19 8L10 17Z" />`,
          "notification": `<path d="m21 19v1h-18v-1l2-2v-6c0-3.1 2-5.8 5-6.7 0-.1 0-.2 0-.3 0-.5.2-1 .6-1.4.4-.4.9-.6 1.4-.6.5 0 1 .2 1.4.6.4.4.6.9.6 1.4 0 .1 0 .2 0 .3 3 .9 5 3.6 5 6.7v6l2 2zm-7 2c0 .5-.2 1-.6 1.4-.4.4-.9.6-1.4.6-.5 0-1-.2-1.4-.6-.4-.4-.6-.9-.6-1.4"/>`,
        } [ is ] +
        `</g></svg>`;
        
        this.onclick = (evt) => alert("You clicked: " + is )
    }
  });
</script>



When you are not going to observe attributes only keep the connectedCallback
Placed in the <head> of your document, there will not be any FOUCs
You can make all paths smaller in size (reducing precision) with https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#
12.5304 precision is like stuffing 9999 "pixels" into 1

Wow! Nice workaround! But, I want to have a Vue component for this stuff as I am working with VueJS fully. Because it is required to do so. Otherwise I could handle it like you show or the other ways. But nice stuff and always works. I loved it. Adding to my gists list.

Then wrap it in a Vue Component. Lit, Angular, Svelte, React Web Component, they are all just wrappers around native technology
